# Can you make a simple 2D ring with a GAN?

Tags: distributions, generative-models, gan

I am trying to model simple 2d continuous distributions with GANs. Here, I focus on a 2d distribution following a ring structure. The architecture of my networks are:

```
def make_generator_model(input_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_shape=(input_dim,)))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))  # output dim=2
    model.summary()
    return model
```

```
def make_discriminator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_shape=(2,)))  # input data dim=2
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # output dim=1 because discriminator
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I have trained my models to minimize the standard loss of GAN architectures, using `Adam(learning_rate=5e-4)` for 1000 epochs. I report the Discriminator average prediction per epoch on the GIF, separated between fake and genuine data. Blue points are the training data, orange points are simulated by the Generator.

**Why can't my GAN even capture such a simple 2d distribution?**

I have tried different architectures: more layers, less layers, more nodes, less nodes, larger learning rate, lower learning rates... and even the Wasserstein GAN architecture, in vain.

Any insight would be much welcome :)

[image]

Comment: IIUC, it doesn't converge. This is one of a couple of common problems with GANs. Maybe this helps: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/problems

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I have tried the Wasserstein GAN in vain...
This is very surprising that GANs can generate high-level realistic images, but have a hard time to approximate low dimensional simple distributions

Comment: can you try much, much wider networks? Like width 2,000?